# How to build and use openCV with Netbeans

Tags: java, opencv

When I am using opencv in java with netbeans I have an error. I solved it by right click on the Project->Properties->Click on RUN->VM Options : -Djava.library.path="C:..."-> ok and this has worked for me when run the project in Netbeans, but once the jar is built the same error is back.

This is tutorial of my action:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/717283/How-to-Use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-NetBeans-IDE

Thank for reading my question!

Comment: review: You don't speak of what error you have. Please try to add a stacktrace or descripe the error.

Comment: Thank you every body! My error : 
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java248 in java.library.path"

i was solve it, In netbean after click Project->Properties->Click on RUN->VM Options : -Djava.library.path="C:..." i click make new config and that run ok. Thank Sir !

Comment: its worked
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272164/cannot-run-opencv-with-java-in-eclipe-netbeans-or-intellij-idea-java-library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272164/cannot-run-opencv-with-java-in-eclipe-netbeans-or-intellij-idea-java-library)